# This stateless iterator supposed to be an infinite loop without a conditional statement, but it don't

Tags: while-loop, lua, iterator, infinite-loop

In the previous question, I have asked about an iterator that would create an infinite loop(`print nil`), and learnt about how important the conditional statement is. Well, for some reasons,this iterator didn't create the infinite loop despite not having the conditional statement.

```
local function OnlyStrings(s)

  local function Iter(s, pos) 
    pos = pos + 1 
    --[[After assigned pos + 1 to pos, "while" will look at the condition again then see
    whether it's a string or not -- ]] 
    
    while type(s[pos]) ~= "string" do 
      pos = pos + 1 
    end 
    
    return pos, s[pos] 
    --pos is the control variable, it's supposed to + 1 forever without a conditional statement
  end
  return Iter, s, 0
end 
local t = {"bruh", 1, 2, "yep", true}
for i, string in OnlyStrings(t) do 
  print(string)
  --[[bruh
      yep ]] --
end
```

Well, I assume that `while` was involved with the reason why this iterator didn't become an infinite loop. Like, Is `while` act as the conditional statement ? Had `while` used `break` after it got `nil`?

Comment: When I try it keeps looping until the program aborts...

Comment: ah I see, I tried to add `print("pos")` inside `while` loop and it was printing forever until I stopped the program. It printed twice so I thought `Iter` wasn't an inifnite loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code ends up in an infinite loop.

```
while type(s[pos]) ~= "string" do 
  pos = pos + 1 
end
```

will run forever as soon as soon as you've reached the last element of `s[pos]`.

Comment: ah, I see, I thought it wasn't an infinite loop because it only printed twice. But the loop yielded due to `while` loop, thus it will never reach `return pos, s[pos`.